# C# PasswordDeriveBytes: seems that Salt does'nt matter

Tags: c#, salt, cryptostream

probably I misunderstood something.
The following code produces two equal keys by CryptDeriveKey with two different salt.

That is the console result:

salt1: 21 3e 18 a3 9a 8b 5f

--> Key da 89 ea 3d 91 08 20 98 20 e9 dc 45 d5 97 10 7f 8f 4a 52 15 26 68 ef 83

salt2: 9e db 4c 2b 49 b4 24

--> Key da 89 ea 3d 91 08 20 98 20 e9 dc 45 d5 97 10 7f 8f 4a 52 15 26 68 ef 83

What is my mistake?

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace PasswordDeriveBytes_SaltDoesntMatter
{
    class Program
    {
        // for usage in CreateAndPrintKeyAndSalt
        private static readonly string password = "secret123";
        private static readonly TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] salt1 = new byte[] { 33, 62, 24, 163, 154, 139, 95 };
            byte[] salt2 = new byte[] { 158, 219, 76, 43, 73, 180, 36 };

            // a TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider-instance for getting an IV

            CreateAndPrintKeyAndSalt("salt1", salt1);
            CreateAndPrintKeyAndSalt("salt2", salt2);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// print the salt and the CryptDeriveKey based on this salt
        /// !! uses the const password and cryptoServiceProvider
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="saltName">name of the used salt</param>
        /// <param name="salt">the used salt</param>
        /// <param name="cryptoServiceProvider"></param>
        private static void CreateAndPrintKeyAndSalt(string saltName, byte[] salt)
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, salt);
            byte[] aKey = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, cryptoServiceProvider.IV);
            Console.WriteLine($"{saltName}: {ByteArrayInHexText(salt)} --> Key {ByteArrayInHexText(aKey)}");
        }    

        /// <summary>
        /// returns a Textstring of each byte in arr in hex-formatting separated by space
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arr">the array</param>
        /// <returns>the formatted string</returns>
        public static string ByteArrayInHexText(byte[] arr)
        {
            string s = "";
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                s += $" {item:x2}";
            }
            return s.Substring(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/04/14/generating-a-key-from-a-password/) MSDN blog:

> When calling CryptDeriveKey, the salt and iteration count that are set
>   on the PasswordDeriveBytes object are not used, so even having
>   different salts and iteration counts will produce the same key given
>   that the rest of the inputs are also the same.