# PasswordDeriveBytes only depends on the password, not salt or IV

Tags: c#, cryptography

I need to create a `.netstandard2.0` C# library that derives a symmetric key from a password. Therefore, I cannot use many of new, fancy classes that Microsoft provides, and need to stick with `PasswordDeriveBytes`.

My PoC quite followed the one in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes):

```cs
// use .netstandard2.0 kdf to derive the key
int kdfIterations = 10000;

// some random values
var salt = new byte[] { 18, 25, 36, 78, 96, 174, 56, 96, 47, 12, 13, 14, 47, 47, 36, 49 };
var iv = new byte[] { 17, 6, 9, 53, 207, 8, 0, 16, 47, 89, 44, 22, 33, 44, 77, 15 };

byte[] key = iv;
var passwordDeriveBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes("mySuperSecretPassword", salt);
for (int i = 0; i < kdfIterations; i++)
{   
    key = passwordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA256", 192, key.Take(8).ToArray());
}
```

But as a matter of fact I have revealed that when I swap `salt` and `iv`, the derived key value stays the same. Bummer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216842/11926950) provides an explanation that `salt` is not used indeed. But when you play with it, you realize that `iv` value to the `CryptDeriveKey()` actually does not matter either, whatever the number of `kdfIterations`, the result does not change. In other words, **derived key only depends on the password itself**. That seems like *very* crappy implementation indeed. Is that true or am I missing something?

I can come up with a workaround like

```cs
// use .netstandard2.0 kdf to derive the key
int kdfIterations = 10000;

// some random values
var salt = new byte[] { 18, 25, 36, 78, 96, 174, 56, 96, 47, 12, 13, 14, 47, 47, 36, 49 };
var iv = new byte[] { 17, 6, 9, 53, 207, 8, 0, 16, 47, 89, 44, 22, 33, 44, 77, 15 };

byte[] key = iv;
for (int i = 0; i < kdfIterations; i++)
{   
    using var passwordDeriveBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes($"{Convert.ToBase64String(key)}mySuperSecretPassword{Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}", salt);
    key = passwordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA256", 192, key.Take(8).ToArray());
}
```

which already takes `salt`, `iv` and `kdfIterations` into account, but I believe the documentation should actually warn that `iv` and `salt` are there just showcasing. Which is incredible for me, as I majored in cryptography.

Comment: `PasswordDeriveBytes` supports two logics, one is an MS extended (proprietary) implementation of the PBKDF1 algorithm, the other is a wrapper around CAPI's `CryptDeriveKey()` function. The first conciders salt and iteration count, the latter not (and seemingly also not the IV), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/shawnfa/generating-a-key-from-a-password#cryptderivekey)  and also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71284660/9014097).